# получение элементов из бд по id Spring Boot

Tags: html, spring-boot, crud

В моей базе данных есть 3 разных строки с разными элементами:
[image: скрин таблицы бд]

Как можно вывести по одной строке на разные части страницы? Попробовал через th:if, но на странице отображается некорректно. То есть место выделяется под все элементы, но вывовыдится только элемент по id

[image: некорректное отображение элементов]

[image: некорректное отображение элементов]

Пока html выглядит так:

```
    <div class="mySlides w3-display-container w3-center">
        <img th:src="@{/img/img1.jpg}" style="width:100%">
        <div class="w3-display-bottommiddle w3-container w3-text-white w3-padding-32 w3-hide-small">
            <div class="square" th:each="home: ${home}">
                <span th:if="${home.id == 1}">
                    <h3 th:text="${home.title}"></h3>
                    <p><b th:text="${home.text}"></b></p>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides w3-display-container w3-center">
        <img th:src="@{/img/img2.jpg}" style="width:100%">
        <div class="w3-display-bottommiddle w3-container w3-text-white w3-padding-32 w3-hide-small">
            <div class="square" th:each="home: ${home}">
                <span th:if="${home.id == 2}">
                    <h3 th:text="${home.title}"></h3>
                    <p><b th:text="${home.text}"></b></p>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides w3-display-container w3-center">
        <img th:src="@{/img/img3.jpg}" style="width:100%">
        <div class="w3-display-bottommiddle w3-container w3-text-white w3-padding-32 w3-hide-small">
            <div class="square" th:each="home: ${home}">
                <span th:if="${home.id == 3}">
                    <h3 th:text="${home.title}"></h3>
                    <p><b th:text="${home.text}"></b></p>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Контроллер этой странички:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private HomeRepository homeRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        Iterable<Home> home = homeRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("home", home);
        return "index";
    }
}
```